# Android App Links - Getting 404 on assetlinks.json

Tags: android, next.js, azure-webapps

I have a website that just went live and getting hits from users accessing using any type of devices.
In my logs I am having 404 requests on the assetlinks.json file.

According to my research this corresponds to Android App Links but I do not have any Android application...

How can I avoid having 404 on this file? Can I create an empty file?

Comment: "I do not have any Android application" -- somebody does, with the domain name you chose for your site. "How can I avoid having 404 on this file?" -- why would you want to do that?

Comment: It is not possible to have an application pointing to that URL.

We are notifying users by email and SMS and they basically click the link from their devices to open the website using the browser... is this also normal to trigger this 404 on the assetlinks.json?

Since there is no application to open that URL how can I configure the website to avoid having calls to the assetlinks.json?

Comment: "It is not possible to have an application pointing to that URL" -- sure it is. All that is required is that some Android app developer used your domain name when setting up deep links. That was not a wise choice by that developer, but it is certainly possible. "is this also normal to trigger this 404 on the assetlinks.json?" -- not as far as I know. "how can I configure the website to avoid having calls to the assetlinks.json?" -- so long as there are 1+ apps out there configured with your domain name, those requests will still be made.

Comment: Is there anyway to figure out which application is this? As far as I know there is really no application but if there is a way to investigate that I would like to try and find out.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: "Is there anyway to figure out which application is this?" -- I cannot think of anything. If it is a real request, it would be coming from the Android OS, not an app -- the app simply has a configuration that causes the OS to make the request. I have never looked at the request, such as its headers, to see if there is anything in there that might provide clues as to what app is causing the OS to issue the request.